# In the category page if i click the add to cart button need to redirect into the specific product page in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, redirect, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

I need to redirect the specific product page when i click the add to cart button in the category page. instead of add the product to the shopping cart in magento 2.3.2

If anyone know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure since i'm new to magento.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to override list.phtml file in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

and replace the code below:

**From**

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
<form data-role="tocart-form"
      data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
      method="post">
    <input type="hidden"
           name="product"
           value="<?=  $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=  Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
           value="<?=  $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
            class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

**To**

```
<button title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
        class="action primary">
    <a href="<?= $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span></a>
</button>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hello Naresh, I have copied core list.phtml file code and replaced the code which you have shared. but still if i click the add to cart button, add the product to the shopping cart. instead of open the specific product.

Comment: Code updated. please check with updated code and let me know it's working for you or not

Comment: thank you naresh. it's working fine.